# Running PhantomJS from PHP with exec()

Tags: php, phantomjs, sh, shared-hosting

I've got the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0
phantomjs --version
```

It try to run it from the following PHP script:

```
<?php
$result = shell_exec('sh test.sh'); 
echo $result;
?>
```

This script return the following error:

```
[Thu Jun 19 10:31:31 2014] [error] [client] test.sh: line 3: phantomjs: command not found
```

I tried to run `phantomjs -v` by hand in a console, and it runs fine. I checked the `PATH`, and phantomjs is correctly defined and found.

The execution environment is a virtual Server with LiveConfig.
Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PATH` probably lacks the location for the phantomjs executable. PhantomJS is probably installed in `/usr/local/bin` so you need to add this to your `PATH` variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
phantomjs --version
```

To check what the current `PATH` is, you could begin the shell script with:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

It could be an issue with shell_exec() and line breaks,
try adding "2>&1" to the string you are passing:

```
$result = shell_exec('sh test.sh 2>&1');
```

this worked for me, found it in the top comment [here, naturally ;)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
         exec('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs path/somescript.js');
?>
```

Yes. Sometimes phantomjs don't need full path in some environment without generate any error. However, sometimes it does.

Always use the full path for all argument in the php command.

Did you use the fullpath for hello.js?

Answer (score -1):

Do not use exec(). Never. It's a bad way.

Use the [php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) and [PhantomJS Runner](https://github.com/Dachande663/PHP-PhantomJS) instead.

Comment: Why? php-phantomjs is a separate API. PhantomJS Runner also uses `shell_exec`. What's your argument?

Comment: Artjom, exec is on the list of potentially dangerous functions, and because on many web hostings your product will not work. Therefore the use of exec is considered bad programming style.

However, if there is no other way...