# Running PhantomJS through exec() - issue with including ~/.fonts

Tags: php, linux, apache, phantomjs, exec

I am able to run PhantomJS from both the shell and `exec()` fine. The server I am using looks for additional fonts in the `~/.fonts/` directory. When those additional fonts are present, *from the shell only* I am able to take a screenshot with PhantomJS and the expected fonts render well.

```
> strace ~/public_html/api/libraries/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs ~/public_html/api/libraries/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/examples/rasterize.js http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/typography/web-fonts/ ~/tmp/test.jpg | grep font
```

> open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/verdana.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
>   open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/AndaleMo.TTF", O_RDONLY) = 11 
>   open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/arial.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
>   open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/cour.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
>   open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/georgia.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
>   open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/impact.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
>   ...

When I try the same command from from `exec()`, the user fonts directory is not searched.

```
<?php
exec('strace ~/public_html/api/libraries/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs ~/public_html/api/libraries/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/examples/rasterize.js http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/typography/web-fonts/ ~/tmp/test.jpg | grep font');
```

The `~/.fonts` directory is not searched, but a screenshot is written to disk without the proper fonts being rendered.

---

I understand `exec()` to run as the Apache user so user fonts won't be used. However,

```
> whoami
```

> user1

and

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
```

> user1

both show as the same user, so I suspect this is misleading because this works perfectly (fonts and all) in the shell:

```
php -r "exec('~/public_html/api/libraries/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs ~/public_html/api/libraries/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/examples/rasterize.js http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/typography/web-fonts/ ~/tmp/test.jpg');"
```

---

I understand `setuid` can allow users to exec a program with the permissions of its owner (user1), but this doesn't help. This particular server is a shared server, and `su` and `sudo` are disabled so running as a different user is not permitted.

Linux user configurations isn't my area of expertise, but **using `exec()` how to run the PhantomJS command so the user fonts are included?**

---

Research:

- [Running PhantomJS from PHP with exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300717/running-phantomjs-from-php-with-exec) - the problem was with $PATH
- [PHP + PhantomJS Rasterize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392407/php-phantomjs-rasterize?rq=1) - This was a problem with HostGator
- [exec() and phantomjs issue with absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672586/exec-and-phantomjs-issue-with-absolute-paths) - One answer suggested running the command as a cron which won't work. Also modifying `/etc/sudoers` is not possible.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - problem occurs only when script is loaded via web server (command line execution works correctly)? If yes - I'd say that the problem may be related with non-interactive shell.

Comment: @radmen Yes, the problem only occurs with `exec()`. I expected that the PHP should run as `www-data`, but `exec('whoami')` returns with the elevated user - user1. However, even though whoami is saying that the script is executing as user1, it doesn't have access to the user fonts, which is my ultimate goal for using PhantomJS through `exec()`.

Comment: PHP has something like `shell_exec()` it may behave a bit different then `exec()` - maybe try this?

Comment: @radmen Unfortunately variants of exec like shell_exec, system, and passthru all behave similarly.

Comment: Ouch. As I said earlier - this may be related with the fact, that `exec()` may call shell in non-interactive mode. I've seen that sometimes non-interactive shell behaves differently then interactive one. This can also affect applications. I've found that in some cases it's good to run `fc-cache` before running Phantom. Maybe you can try this? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302801

Comment: @radmen Thank you. I'll looking into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem revealed itself when `printenv` and `exec('printenv')` were run, respectively

```
HOME=/home/user1
```

and

```
HOME=/home/user1/tmp
```

This means that even though `whoami` and `exec('whoami')` both return `user1`, something in the shared host configuration set the home directory to `/tmp`, which is wise to sandbox the script.

The solution is to prepend `export HOME=~;` (**not** `HOME=~;`) to the exec command. i.e.

```
exec('export HOME=~; strace ~/public_html/api/libraries/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs ~/public_html/api/libraries/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/examples/rasterize.js http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/typography/web-fonts/ ~/tmp/test.jpg | grep font');
```

This will cause the `HOME` directory to be set and the user fonts can now be searched.